# Laracasts/Flash not creating html for flash

Tags: laravel-5

I have installed Laracasts/Flash package and have been using it successfully for a while. I recently made some changes to my code and added another service provider and now, suddenly Laracasts/Flash is not magically creating the flash message pop-up modal. On my local dev environment it does, but not in production :(. In one of my controllers I run this code:

```
flash()->overlay("Your content may take a few minutes to be processed.", "Thanks for your submission!");
Log::info( $request->session()->all());
```

and I checked my logs to find the session data:

```
[2017-05-18 02:07:08] local.INFO: array (
'_token' => 'somestring',
'backUrl' => 'https://example.com/posts',
'_previous' => 
array (
  'url' => 'https://example.com/posts/create',
),
'flash' => 
array (
  'old' => 
  array (
  ),
  'new' => 
  array (
    0 => 'flash_notification',
  ),
),
'login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d' => 1,
'flash_notification' => 
Illuminate\Support\Collection::__set_state(array(
   'items' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    Laracasts\Flash\OverlayMessage::__set_state(array(
       'title' => 'Thanks for your submission!',
       'overlay' => true,
       'message' => 'Your content may take a few minutes to be processed.',
       'level' => 'info',
       'important' => false,
    )),
  ),
)),
```

)

although in the environment where it works it looks like this:

```
 'flash_notification' => 
  array (
    'message' => 'Your content may take a few minutes to be processed.',
    'level' => 'info',
    'overlay' => true,
    'title' => 'Thanks for your submission!',
  ),
```

So Laracasts/Flash is creating the session data, but then in the returned view there is no flash message. Meaning when I check the source of the web page that is returned I do not see `<div id="flash-overlay-modal" class="modal fade flash-modal"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header">...` that I do when Laracasts/Flash normally creates a flash message. Anyone have any ideas about what the problem could be?

I am using Laravel 5.2.45.

Also I am including the flash view by `@include('flash::message')`

I have been digging around. I published the flash vendor files so that now I can edit the flash::message view and I put some test text at the top of the file and it shows up, however the first if statment in the view `@if (Session::has('flash_notification.message'))` never passes.

In my local env when I do `Log::info($request->session()->get('flash_notification'));` I get this output:

```
[2017-05-18 05:30:00] local.INFO: array (
  'message' => 'Your content may take a few minutes to be processed.',
  'level' => 'info',
  'overlay' => true,
  'title' => 'Thanks for your submission!',
)
```

in my production I get this output:

```
[2017-05-18 17:42:21] local.INFO: [{"title":"Thanks for your submission!","overlay":true,"message":"Your content may take a few minutes to be processed.","level":"info","important":false}]
```

Comment: Did you install the new Service Provider on production? Have you checked your error log?

Comment: The new service provider is laravel markdown. I did run a composer update on production and saw that it was installed and followed the install instructions (same as local env). I checked error log and there is an error. Probably there will be some stupid mistake here :|

Comment: It looks like you're returning a `View` somewhere where Laravel expects a `Response`.

Comment: @fubar I checked again and actually those error's were not related to this issue. I tried it again and they did not come up now and still no flash message.

Comment: You get errors about being unable to set a cookie, call `send` on a `View`, etc, when you don't provide a CSRF token?? I'd expect you to get a CSRF Exception instead. In that case with the information at hand, I don't know.